# Snowflake - Read comma delimited payload with commas between double quotes?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to read a comma delimited payload in **Snowflake**, which can have commas between double quotes in some columns?
For instance:
`(o,"sadasdasd",123123123,"this is an example, of data field, with commas and backslashes\ which should be read as one unique column",0,...)`

So far, I am using:

```
with your_table as 
(select json_text:message::string as payload from table)
split_part(payload,',',1) as firstfield, 
...
from 
your_table
```

Comment: I assume the data is already in Snowflake, then?  If this was a file, it'd be pretty easy to load into separate columns correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JavaScript UDF that can do it:

```
create or replace function SPLIT_QUOTED_STRING(STR string)
returns array
language javascript
as
$$
var arr = STR.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/['"]+/g, '')
}
return arr;
$$;

select split_quoted_string('o,"sadasdasd",123123123,"asdasdasd.www.org,123123,link.com",0');

-- To get a member of the array:
select split_quoted_string('o,"sadasdasd",123123123,"asdasdasd.www.org,123123,link.com",0')[1]::string;
```

If you want to split into a table instead of an array, use the FLATTEN table function:

```
select "VALUE"::string as MY_VALUE
from table(flatten (split_quoted_string('o,"sadasdasd",123123123,"asdasdasd.www.org,123123,link.com",0')));
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Greg. In my case, I want to keep all data in between quotes as one unique data field. Any suggestions on that? I revised the example to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you want it as an array or a table? Remember that in Snowflake literals you have to double the backslashes, so can you show how it exists in your data?

Comment: Table. backslashes do not need to be in the final result. Current I want to read all columns.

Comment: Updated to show how to flatten from an array output to a table. You could also convert the UDF to a UDTF, but flatten works fine.

Comment: How to make this work when the data contains empty strings? for example: 'o,"sadasdasd",123123123,"asdasdasd.www.org,123123,link.com",0,,123.67'. There is an empty field before the field containing value of 123.67. The result should now have an empty field for the 6th column and then a value of 123.67 for the 7th column.

Comment: And sometimes, the data itself has double quotes. Got to take care of that as well.